# Fill an array of linked lists with a dictionary file

Tags: c

Edit, okay. So, my code is mostly working at the moment. I know it is missing some words that should be misspelled. Not sure why, though.

http://pastebin.com/DSNU16Bf

This link has all of the other links to my files. Since, I can only post two links at a time.

If you read the files. You will see how it all works. My search is super ghetto, I know. I couldn't figure out a way to ignore the linked list if it started with a different letter, everything I did made infinite loops. This compiles and works, though.

It's not picking up all of the slang words.

Comment: Please post a **small** sample of your input file, a few dozen lines should be sufficient, so long as the format is consistent. Thanks. Note: post it **in an addendum to your question; NOT in a comment here.** Also, the definition of `LENGTH` may come into play here, so please include that in your source.

Comment: The whole file is one word followed by a new line. No random blank lines or extra spaces or anything or the sort. Nothing that is having an effect on the transition.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around the code needed to switch to the next node. I tried:
    if(strncmp(str1,str2,1) != 0){
        i++
    }

And many similar attempts to using a prev = wordArr[0], then comparing prev to line. But, it just wasn't working like I it should.

Comment: Your code does not even compile "if(opened){" where does `opened` come from? and you say you are a student from Harvard?

Comment: @haincha Your first intention, if I understand the problem set correctly, should be a fixed dictionary "table" indexed by the first *character* of a word. Example: "apple" will be placed in linked list in the `table['a']` slot. Likewise, "Desktop" would be in the list at `table['d']` (and if you think I chose two words with different cases for their first letters ('a', 'D') accidentally, you'd be wrong).

Comment: This isn't the complete code... I never said I needed help with compiling my code. Get off your high horse, please. Here is my full set of code, which is not working at the moment, like I said. I have had it able to put everything in Node[0], but my goal is all "a"s in Node[0] "b"s in Node[1] and so on. if(opened) is a check for a different part of my program file.

http://pastebin.com/TKFgLPpQ - dictionary.c
http://pastebin.com/hmFYAbcQ - dictionary.h

Edit: Yes, you're exactly right, Whoz. The tables should be indexed by first letter. But, if you check my pastebin, the compares are all lower

Comment: Also, your "a","D" comparison is okay. The whole dictionary file is lowercase letters. Comparing all lower case letters to lowercase letters.

Comment: @haincha since you pasted everything else, can you throw your dictionary file up on pastebin as well. I kinda need it to test something, if its not too much trouble. They really kind of cheat with the whole file anyway, as it is fully-alphabetic. they could have really made your life entertaining and had it in random order.

Comment: Too big for pastebin, but I have it linked from my Dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qk3h75ab60e71rg/large

Answer (score 2):

Here is my critique

```
bool load(const char* dictionary){
// TODO
FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
if(opened){
    fclose(dict);
    return false;
}
```

No idea where `opened` come from - guess you opened the file before hand and hence we do not know if the file pointer is at the start, end, or somewhere in the middle

```
opened = true;
if(dict == NULL || !dict){
    return false;
}
```

Why the `!dict`?

```
char line[LENGTH];
bool filling;
for(int i = 0; i < LLLength; i++){
    struct dict_node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(dict_node));
    wordArr[i] = newNode;
    start[i] = wordArr[i];
}
```

So here you are constructing 27 nodes. This is a simpler version (and the same)

```
for(int i = 0; i < LLLength; i++){
        struct dict_node *newNode;
        start[i] = malloc(sizeof(dict_node));
    }
```

Then lets read the file

```
while(!feof(dict)){
    for(int i = 0; i < LLLength; i++){
        filling = true;
        while(filling)
            fgets(line,LENGTH,dict);
```

We get to this point (1 of 27 and a line of at most 45 characters)

So lets pop it into that array. `start[i]` or `wordArrd[i]` whatever you prefer

As we do not know if `wordArr[i]->word` is an array of characters or just a pointer - I am unable to help you here

```
        strcpy(wordArr[i]->word,line);
        prev = wordArr[i];
```

Now we are confused. You started off with an array but schizophrenia set in - we want a linked list.

```
            wordArr[i]->next = malloc(sizeof(dict_node));
            wordArr[i] = wordArr[i]->next;
            fgets(line,LENGTH,dict);
            strcpy(wordArr[i]->word,line);
    }
}
```

...

```
fclose(dict);
for(int i = 0; i < LLLength; i++){
    wordArr[i] = start[i];
    while(wordArr[i]->next != NULL){
        wordArr[i] = wordArr[i]->next;
        count++;
    }
}

int test = 0;
wordArr[test] = start[test];
while(wordArr[test]->next != NULL){
    printf("%s",wordArr[test]->word);
    wordArr[test] = wordArr[test]->next;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't really with the code I currently have. It is what I don't have. I appreciate a few of the suggestions you made, will make my code look less ridiculous. The if(opened) part is because there is a check made to make sure I closed the file. If for whatever reason the dictionary isn't closed before, it is now.

The real issue I am faced with. Is when I read a line, I store it into my wordArr[0]->word and I want to compare the previous word with the next line. If they don't start with the same first char, I want to i++ and add b's to wordArr[1].

Comment: @haincha - Your logic is all over the place - it does not make any sense. As to helping you at least give use the structure for `wordArr` - Do you want this as an array or a linked list? Difficult to tell from the OP.

Comment: struct dict_node *wordArr[LLLength]; I know my code is all over the place. My code isn't the issue at the moment. It's my logic. I don't know how to convey in code to tell the array to switch to wordArr[1] when a "b" word comes along. Everything I have come up with Seg faults, infinite loops, or populates the whole dictionary in Node[0]. I want an array of linked lists. Array a-z with each having all of the letters with their corresponding first letter.

Comment: @EdHeal he wants an array of linked lists (i.e. an array of linked list pointers), so either the answer to both your questions is yes, or no, depending on how you look a it. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig - From the OP it is not clear as to what that person is trying to achieve. Why 27 when going down the linked list route? Why 4 characters for a line. ... Very confusing and perhaps that person need to stop coding and take a back seat. Ruminate and digest what is required.

Comment: @EdHeal I concur completely. Sometimes you gotta stop and just say "wtf am I really trying to do, and do I know how to do it?"